# Powershell Get-ChildItem seems to sometimes skip files

Tags: windows, powershell, get-childitem

I wrote a powershell script to upload files that are created in a local folder to SharePoint with Add-PnPFile.

I loop the script every 20 seconds to check the folder for new files and then upload if the file is not on SharePoint yet. I use a Where-object to select only the last 5 minutes to not have to much files in the loop. (it needs to upload fast since flow is ERP->Local folder-> SharePoint and users are waiting)

This works like 95% of the time but sometimes it skips a files that is existing.

```
$Localfolder = "D:\DATA"
$A_Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Localfolder -Include @("*.pdf", "*.csv") | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)}
```

If I stop the script and run in the same Powershell session, it doesn't show the file.
If I open another powershell session and run the command it shows the file.

Anyone know if there is caching or I'm missing something?

> PS C:\Users\rob_admin> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value

---

PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1018
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1018
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

Comment: $Localfolder = "D:\DATA" = $Localfolder = "D:\DATA\*" Because I tested if it's not the -Recurse setting

Comment: Is it ... a problem? Won't the file get picked up when you run the script again in 20 seconds?

Comment: Don't poll. Ever. Respond to events instead. Suddenly you have a solution that doesn't burn CPU cycles needlessly. And happens to be reliable.

Comment: So the file is missing even if you run `Get-ChildItem -Path $Localfolder -Include @("*.pdf", "*.csv")` by itself, without the filter?

Comment: How are these files created? Is there a chance that they are still open in another application, while your script runs? In this case you might even upload incomplete files!

Comment: For `-Include` to work, you need to either end the path in `\*` OR add the `-Recurse` switch to `Get-ChildItem`

Comment: Yes file is missing in the next Cycle of the while loop.
CPU and RAM is not a problem, it's just that it sometimes not showing the file, even if you stop the script and run only the Get-childitem command.

Answer (score 0):

I start using a different approach which has a 100% success rate after IInspectable  comment:
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher

So the trigger is now:
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher 'Created' -Action $action